# How can i print values from an observable array of objects returned by service in Angular 5?

Tags: angular, angular5

A service will call & get the information of blobs from server. I need to print the details of each of the blob in my component.

The angular service part works fine and fetches the data. What is the correct way to define the component.ts and html?

**Error in browser**

[image]

**Component.html**

```
<div class="col-md-4" *ngFor="let key of blobsList | keys">
<p>
  <a target="_blank" href="{{blobsList[key].blobName}}">
    <img src="{{blobsList[key].blobName}}" width="100px" height="100px" />
  </a>
</p>
<p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#">{{blobsList[key].blobName}}</a></p>
```

**pipe.ts**

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'keys'
})
export class KeysPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    return Object.keys(value);
  }
}
```

**Component.ts**

```
this.blobService.getAllBlobsJS() {
  .subscribe(
    (val) => {
      console.log("..val =", val);
    },
    response => {
      console.log(" in error", response);
    },
    () => {
      console.log(" observable is now completed.");
    });
  console.log("..values=", this.bList);
}
```

**Service**

```
getAllBlobsJS(): Observable<Azureblob[]> {
  return new Observable(obs=>{
    var localArr: Azureblob[] = [];
    this.blobServiceObj = AzureStorageBlobServiceJS.createBlobService(this.connectionString);
    this.blobList = this.blobServiceObj.listBlobsSegmented('acs', null, 
      function (error, results) {
        if (error) {
          console.log("**** Error");
          obs.error();
        } else {
          for (var i = 0, blob; blob = results.entries[i]; i++) {
            console.log("Blob ", i, blob);
            localArr.push(new Azureblob(blob.name));
          }
        }
        console.log("localArr - # of blobs returned=", localArr.length);
        return localArr;
      });
     obs.next(this.blobList);
     obs.complete();
 })}
```

Comment: show the part where you are assigning `blobsList`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure what syntax you're using here. There are a lot of issues with the syntax:

```
console.log("..values=", this.bList);
```

The above line will run synchronously. So you might not get the `bList` initialized. You've also not assigned `val` from your success callback of the subscribe block to `this.bList`

Change this:

```
this.blobService.getAllBlobsJS() {
  .subscribe(
    (val) => {
      console.log("..val =", val);
    },
    response => {
      console.log(" in error", response);
    },
    () => {
      console.log(" observable is now completed.");
    });
  console.log("..values=", this.bList);
}
```

To this correct syntax:

```
this.blobService.getAllBlobsJS()
  .subscribe(
    val => {
      console.log("..val =", val);
      this.bList = val;
    },
    error => console.log("in error", error),
    () => console.log(" observable is now completed.")
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

`this.blobServiceObj.listBlobsSegmented()` doesn't **return** anything. But yet you emit what it returns (undefined) from your observable.

The same way as you're emitting the error from inside the callback, you should emit the successful event, and complete, from there:

```
getAllBlobsJS(): Observable<Azureblob[]> {
  return new Observable(obs => {
    this.blobServiceObj = AzureStorageBlobServiceJS.createBlobService(this.connectionString);
    this.blobServiceObj.listBlobsSegmented('acs', null, (error, results) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log("**** Error");
        obs.error();
      } else {
        const event = results.entries.map(blob => new Azureblob(blob.name));
        obs.next(event);
        obs.complete();
      }
    });
  });
}
```

The next problem is that you're trying to iterate through blobsList, but thie property doesn't exist in your component, and is never populated anywhere. 
And even if it was, you would need to make sure it's initialized before trying to apply your keys pipe on it.